# Tabulator editor select dropdown not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, tabulator

I am working with tabulator. Table have a column with select editor.

Problem is that the pulldown menu does not show if the pulldown menu overflows from the window. But if i do not set the width like `width: 900px` of the div in which the table resides. It also works properly if the window is small and horizontal scroll appears. I really want to have the minimum 980px width otherwise the tooltips do not work correctly. How do i properly render the pulldown menu every time?

To see the problem better kindly see this [video](https://youtu.be/XyrQLc0T2Nk).

Code for the tabulator table

```
var column = [
{title: "No", field:"row_number", align:"center", width:55, frozen:true, cssClass: "disable_edit"},
{title: messages_etc_data["WEB_0600_002_001"], field: "class_notation", width: 180, align: "left", editor: false, frozen:true, headerFilter:true, cssClass: "disable_edit"}, //種別
{title: messages_etc_data["WEB_0600_002_002"], field: "code_notation", width: 180, align: "left", editor: false, frozen:true, headerFilter:true, cssClass: "disable_edit"},  //名称
{title: messages_etc_data["WEB_0600_002_003"]+"<label class=\"required\"></label><a id='t_ancher1'><img class='book'></a>", field: "ztotal_external_code", width: 170, 
        align: "left", editor: "select", cssClass: "editable_column", editorParams:{ values:param_shiharai_media_lookup}, validator:[ztotal_validator]},   //ZTOTAL出力
{title: "登録", field: "ztotal_null_flg", width: 20, align: "center", editor: false, visible: false, formatter:"lookup", formatterParams:{"0":"◯", "1":"✕"}},
{   // Column group
    title: messages_etc_data["WEB_0600_002_004"],
    align: "left",
    columns: [
        {title: messages_etc_data["WEB_0600_002_005"]+"<label class=\"required\"></label><a id='t_ancher2'><img class='book'></a>", field: "ttend_external_code_1", width: 160, 
            align: "center", editor: "input", tooltip: messages_etc_data["WEB_0600_000_025"], cssClass: "editable_column", validator:["maxLength: 2"], 
            mutatorEdit:zero_padding, mutatorEditParams:{length_with_pad:2}},  //メディア種別
        {title: messages_etc_data["WEB_0600_002_006"]+"<label class=\"required\"></label><span class=\"help-tooltip\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"left\" data-html=\"true\"></span>", 
            field: "ttend_external_code_3", width: 160, align: "left", editor: "input", tooltip: messages_etc_data["WEB_0600_000_026"], cssClass: "editable_column",
            validator:["maxLength: 3"], mutatorEdit:zero_padding, mutatorEditParams:{length_with_pad:3}},    //券種コード
        {title: "登録", field: "ttend_null_flg", width: 20, align: "center", editor: false, visible: false, formatter:"lookup", formatterParams:{"0":"◯", "1":"✕"}}
    ]
}
];

// テーブル設定
table_data_div = new Tabulator("#tabs-1_1",
{
    data: query_parsed_data,
    headerFilterPlaceholder: column_filter_placeholder,
    columns: column,
    rowMouseOver: hover_over_color,
    rowMouseOut: hover_out_color,
    cellEdited: shiharai_newaribiki_cell_edit_callback, // Custom callback function
    rowFormatter: shiharai_newari_row_formatter         // Custom row formatter
});
document.getElementById("shiharai_media").style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

HTML paste for full page [here](https://pastebin.com/ybS30maz). Code written by me is after the file header lines `v_tec_cooperation.php`

Comment: you posted your php code, can you provide us with rendered html code so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @cloned Added full page html from pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/ybS30maz)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, seems to be caused by using display: flex in the containing elements.

Comment: The problem can be fixed by ```autoResize:false``` setting. Reference: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/layout#resize-table